# How to remove (not to hide) ReplyKeyboardMarkup in Telegram.Bot using C#?

Tags: c#, keyboard, bots, telegram

I'm using **Telegram.Bot** library in C# for developing telegram bots.

I post a text message using SendTextMessageAsync() method and sent a Keyboard with it :

```
bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "sample msg", ParseMode.Default, false, false, 0, new InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboardData));
```

I want to remove (not to hide) the keyboard, after click of any user on one of the keyboard buttons, so I use this instruction :

```
int msgId = bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "sample msg", ParseMode.Default, false, false, 0, new InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboardData)).Result;
...
bot.EditMessageReplyMarkupAsync(chatId, msgId, new ReplyKeyboardRemove());
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me about it.

Meanwhile if I set oneTimeKeyboard to true in ReplyKeyboardMarkup, the keyboard will be hide after user click, but it doesn't removed, only it will be hide and user can make it visible using keyboard button of telegram.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ReplyKeyboardRemove](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardremove) method to do that.

Comment: It's not a method. it's a class that is used in EditMessageReplyMarkupAsync() method or SendTextMessageAsync(). if I use it in 1st method, it doesn't work and if I use it in the 2nd method, there will be an extra message.

Comment: Please open issue in your library

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid, it's too late, but you can use `ReplyKeyboardRemove`

```
var send = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "your_text")
{
    ReplyMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardRemove() { RemoveKeyboard = true }
};
await bot.MakeRequestAsync(send);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python users, according to Sean`s comment (telegram documentation):

```
    import telebot
    bot = telebot.TeleBot('YOUR TELEGRAM API CODE HERE')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="YOUR MESSAGE HERE", reply_markup=telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

Comment: The question was about C#...

Comment: Yes, that`s why I started the answer with "For Python users"!

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone.

```
new TelegramBotClient("<token>").SendTextMessageAsync(chat_id, text, replyMarkup: new ReplyKeyboardRemove());
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me :

```
public async Task RemoveRequestContactButton(string chatId, string text)
        {
            var tgBot = GetClient();
            await tgBot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, text, replyMarkup: new ReplyKeyboardRemove()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

where function GetClient() returns  TelegramBotClient;

Answer (score 0):

```
await _bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, "Your text", replyMarkup: new ReplyKeyboardRemove() { Selective = true });
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**